# Register in android a session like value shared by all activity

Tags: java, android

How can I register data (like integer or poco objects) shared by all activity like the id of the user ? Have I to use a simple singleton or is there a special Android way ?

Note : I don't need to make that data persistant (no need of SharedPreferences or sqlite)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own class that implements Application and specify this in your manifest file. In that case, every time you call `getApplicationContext` you will get a reference of your application that can hold any kind of information.

- [How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

Sample code:

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
  public void setMethod() {
    //
  }
}

((MyApplication)getApplicationContext()).setMethod()
```

Comment: `<application android:name=".MyApplication" />`

Answer (score 1):

The android way is to create a custom `Application` for your project. Then in `onCreate` of that application you initialize whatever you need, and for example from an `Activity` do something like:

```
((MyApplication) getApplication()).getMyData()
```

If using [roboguice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) you can use a `@Singleton` injection which basically does the boilerplate of a singleton for you - that's much nicer.